# How to insert Gothic letters in Word?

Tags: notation

I do not manage to find in any of the options provided by Word the real Gothic letters used my German mathematicians in their original works. Noe even under the two "gothic" rubrics. just some sparse cases, which do not help me at all.

Could anyone
1) Tell me how to insert gothic letters (both capital and small) when writing a word document? I have tried copying and pasting from some internet page, but it does not come up correctly on the document.

AND / OR

2) Provide tHe list of Gothic letters here in a way which allows copying and pasting? I have also tried it with some references here, but it did not work either.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't know how to do this in word but personally I'd write the document in LaTeX and use this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60360/how-to-use-fraktur-gothic-fonts-in-text-mode

Comment: That’s not a math question, though.

Comment: It is a question very relavant for math texts....

Comment: \mathfrak{g} and \mathfrak{G} in $\LaTeX$ produce $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{G}$.

Comment: I do not have Latex among my fonts.....How should i proceed?

Comment: @JavierArias Latex isn't a font

Comment: I don't think this should be put on hold. The help center says: Questions about software mathematicans may use are allowed, so I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have Word version 2007 or later, you can use:

> Insert > Equation

And then you can choose between a lot of symbols.

You can also use the command \frakturA or \fraktura, where A and a can be replaced by any letter.

Comment: I will try that.